# How to calculate the energy of the function tri(2t+5/6) using matlab?

Tags: matlab

How to calculate the energy of the function tri(2t+5/6) using matlab?[where tri is triangular pulse function]

Answer (score 1):

Define trisqr square function and integrate over it:

```
trisqr=@(x) tri(x).*tri(x);
xmin=-2;
xmax=2;
Energy=integral(trisqr,xmin,xmax)
```